# What, exactly, is the difference between "host only" and "LAN segment" in VMware?

Tags: networking, virtualization

From what I understand, with *LAN segment* you have to manually create a route (routing table) while *host only* does it for you.

Can someone clarify?

Answer (score 2):

Host-only networking creates a network that is completely contained within the host computer. Host-only networking provides a network connection between the virtual machine and the host system by using a virtual network adapter that is visible on the host operating system. When you install Workstation Pro on a Windows or Linux host system, a host-only network (VMnet1) is set up for you.

A LAN segment is a private network that is shared by other virtual machines, which has to be created manually. You create a LAN segment by configuring virtual machine network settings.

For more details on this topic, below product documentation can be referred.

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-93BDF7F1-D2E4-42CE-80EA-4E305337D2FC.html

https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/16.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-DEE1E2F1-5DA4-4C83-B7C5-A1165C84C757.html